# Event Tracking data isnt showing in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am facing really weird problem related to event tracking. We have implemented google analytics standard code and event tracking for one website and that site is uploaded on online version of test staging sever (not live yet for public).

Google Analytics shows data for pageviews but not showing for event tracking. I looked at code and seems that its working fine.

Anybody has clue what is happening ? Please advise me

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to make sure the `__utm.gif` tracking pixel request for the event is being made. Things to check:

- Javascript errors when the event is triggered.
- Verify `__utm.gif` via the network tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Dev tools, or Fiddler, or [ga_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gaDebug)
- If your'e following a link right after the event is triggered, you may have to add a delay to allow time for the image request to be processed.

A code snippet showing your `_trackEvent` code might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments, it is difficult for us to review and answer. Is it possible for your ti share the URL in which you have incorporated the event tracking.

However, possible reasons could be:
* a silly error in JS.
* proper closer of tags.
* need to set up goals as well (not mandatory though).